# How do I use Column.contents_changed in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm having issues trying to use `Column.contents_changed` in a PySimpleGUI interface.

My scripts works the following way:

1. There is this first mode with empty spaces. As you can see I can reach the bottom of the interface with the scrolling bar at the rigth. All of the layout is embedded in a column element.
   [image]
2. But when the spaces expand as I click GENERATE for the images, I cannot reach the bottom of the interface and access the other items (red arrow: bar reaches the bottom)... In comparison to the first image I can't access the items after the Submit button.
   [image]

I have tried using Column.contents_changed  as it says in the [book reference](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#column-element) putting the following line at the end of the `if  event == "GENERATE"`:

```
layout.column_contents_changed()
```

But the terminal says :

```
** Error 'list' object has no attribute 'contents_changed' **
```

Also tried `window[layout].column_contents_changed()` and it did not worked.

Following the [official example](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Layout_Extend.py) how to use `Column.contents_changed` it says that I need to make a key (-COL-) for the columns and then:

```
layout =[[sg.Column(inside, element_justification = "l", scrollable= True, vertical_scroll_only=True, size= (830,600), key="-COL-")]]

...

window['-COL-'].contents_changed()
```

But it does not work!

Someone knows how can I solve this? If it is necessary more information do not hesitate to request it. Thanks for you attention.

.

Comment: `contents_changed` is a method of scrollable Column element, so you need to find the Column element before call it. Element can be found by `window[key_of_element]`. Now you can call it by `window['-COL-'].contents_changed()` if the key of the scrollable Column element is `'-COL-'`. Note: Remember to call `window.refresh()` to update GUI before you call it.

Comment: @JasonYang it worked! It seems that I needed to use window.refresh() before calling the .contents_changed()